# creating windows hot key?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have folder hierarchy like C > folder1>folder2. If I have to open folder 2 I have to navigate through C > folder1>folder2.

I know we can create custom windows hot keys. what works for me

1. first create shortcut on desktop for folder 2
2. Right click on created shortcut
3. enter shortcut key

Is there a way I don't have to create shortcut on desktop as I want to keep it clean ?

Comment: If you are open to other software, AutoHotKey is a macro scripting language (that does a little more than just macros) and allows you to create any possible combination of hotkeys you like to do anything you want.

Comment: wizongod  I went to https://autohotkey.com/download/ and downloaded. But exe requires admin privilege which I don't have.

Comment: Ah, I'm afraid I can't help you with that. I thought it was your personal computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/134552), to use a custom Windows hotkey, the shortcut must either be located on the Desktop *or* in the Start Menu. As you've stated you don't want to clutter the Desktop, you could consider placing a shortcut in the Start Menu.

> Make sure that the shortcuts for which you want to use shortcut keys
>   are on the desktop, on the Start menu, or in the Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs folder.

Alternatively, you can create the shortcut in one of these locations and set it to `hidden`, which, unless you have set your machine to be able to view hidden files and folders, will give the same functionality but hiding the actual shortcut.

You can do this by:

1. Right click your shortcut and go to `Properties`
2. Click the `General` tab
3. At the bottom section labelled `Attributes`, check `Hidden`.

Once you do this, you won't be able to find the shortcut again through a normal Explorer window without enabling the option to view hidden files and folders.

Note that, as mentioned in a comment, using AutoHotkey could be a possibility. You can create a script on another machine with Admin rights and generate an exe which can then run on any other machine.

Comment: Thanks Jonno. If I make it hidden how can I make it visible back ?

Comment: @emilly In an explorer window, click `View` -> `[Folder] Options)` -> Click the `View` tab and toggle this option on/off as required. http://i.imgur.com/ZkV1b52.jpg

Comment: @Jono when I right click. `send to` option does not show any option to create short cut at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

Comment: @emilly You can create it anywhere and move it there afterwards, or right click and drag the item somewhere and choose `Create shortcuts here`. To be honest, you may need admin privileges for that folder.